# Force angular to change a custom property of an element

Tags: angular

My client bought an Angular template and I need to build the app using this template.

I've this scenario:

```
<div 
     class="sidebar" 
     data-color="white" 
     data-background-color="purple" 
     data-image="../assets/img/sidebar-1.jpg" />
```

this works, but I'd like to change the color using Angular variable, something like :

```
<div 
     class="sidebar" 
     data-color="{{MyColorVariable}}" 
     data-background-color="purple" 
     data-image="../assets/img/sidebar-1.jpg" />
```

But this is not working. I am receiving this error:

Template parse errors:Can't bind to 'color' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.

Yes, things like color or data-color is not really a property of a div. So, Angular refuse it.

Is there some workaround for this ?

Thanks !

Comment: Have you tried `attr.data-color="{{MyColorVariable}}"`? or `[attr.data-color]="MyColorVariable"`

Comment: I think no need curly braces there

Comment: Does this work ? data-color="MyColorVariable"

Comment: Thanks, Zero and Franklin...without brackets this will be considered a static string. Yurzui, this will make the atribute disappear...but was a a nice attempt ! thanks !

Comment: @yurzui's suggestions should work, as you can see in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-n6m6oy). You should also close the `div` with a closing tag.

Comment: Please note that the attribute disappears when the bound value is null.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
constructor(private renderer: Renderer2, private el: ElementRef) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.renderer.setAttribute(this.el.nativeElement, 'color', 'white');
}
```

According to this https://alligator.io/angular/using-renderer2/ it should work, but I have not tested it yet, I don't use custom attributes; will delete the answer if it doesn't work